# How can I make a stacked area chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a stacked area chart:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = term)) +
   geom_area()
```

But this leads to a blank plot.

**[image: blank plot]**

Expected plot (example)

[image: expected]

How can I do this?

```
data <- structure(list(term = c("models", "percentiles", "models:percentiles", 
                                "models", "percentiles", "models:percentiles", 
                                "models", "percentiles", "models:percentiles"), 
                       variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                                            .Label = c("R2", "R5", "R10"), class = "factor"), 
                       value = c(0.435697205847009, 0.533615307749147, 0.0306874864038442, 
                                 0.441369621882273, 0.520198994695284, 0.0384313834224421, 
                                 0.394491546635206, 0.579421546902868, 0.0260869064619254)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only missing the `group` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = term, fill = term)) +
    geom_area(color = "black")
```

[image]